# Get image from database into pdf file

Tags: java, apache, pdf-generation

I am trying to create a pdf file from database and I am stuck at the image part, since Apache pdf box only accepts physical files and the images in my database are in blob format.

```
PDXObjectImage image = new PDJpeg(doc,rs.getBlob("image"));
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I would recommend storing the images on disk and instead store metadata about the images in the database (i.e. location/name etc) unless you really have to store them directly. See this thread, really puts light on the discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay?lq=1

Answer (score 1):

Convert your blob into an `InputStream` and pass this to PDJpeg:

```
Blob imageBlob = rs.getBlob("image");
try (InputStream imageInputStream = imageBlob.getBinaryStream()) {
    PDXObjectImage image = new PDJpeg(doc, imageInputStream);
}
```

Comment: I am probably nit picking, but I would close that imageInputStream with a try with resources :)